# Using SQL to weed out non-alphanumber values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return rows where a column in that row only contains alphanumeric values, and no symbols etc.

> **Table CARS_ALL**
>   **Model**     ----- **Color** ---------           **Owner**
>   
>  Fiat --------- Blue <3 -------         Paul
>   
> Ford   --------          Red !$ƒƒ -----         Sally
>   
> Nissan ----- Red               ------------ Brad

So I want to use a qualifier that will return only the 3rd row, as two of the color values include non-alphanumeric characters

```
Select * FROM CARS_ALL WHERE COLOR LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'
```

But that doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's `LIKE` operator only supports very primitive pattern matching.  Instead, use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS_ALL
WHERE COLOR NOT REGEXP '.*[^A-Za-z0-9].*';
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
Select * 
from CARS_ALL 
where COLOR regexp '^[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$'
```

This assumes that the hyphen is a space.  If it is a hyphen, then it should be included in the character set.

```
Select * 
from CARS_ALL 
where COLOR regexp '^[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$'
```